# Which wordpress filter plugin will collapse in a button "Filters" in mobile devices?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, e-commerce, wordpress-shortcode

I want a product filter plugin for wordpress which should completely collapse in mobile devices as shown in below https://i.stack.imgur.com/SywOJ.png

I have tried the following plugins:

- WOOF- Woocommerce poduct filter
- Themify poduct filter
- Woobewoo poduct filter
  Please help me. I have spent many days to find such filter plugin but found nothing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library etc. are off-topic for Stack Overflow.